# Eclipse Java - Use output of one project as lib in other

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have two projects, "Foo Engine" and "Foo Webapp". Obviously, to run the webapp, I can package Foo as a jar, and link to this jar. But this is time consuming when you are making changes to Foo as well. Is there a way to tell eclipse to continually update the jar in the same way as the in-editor instant-compile system (is this even possible?), and specify the path for this jar (so that it's in the lib folder of webapp).

Thanks!

Edit: Thanks for the advice! I've just realised that the webapp project isn't being compiled by eclipse, but by the webapp framework (play) - so the reference projects option isn't available. I'll see if I can refer to a project in play, if not I'll go back to jar packaging...

wtf? I'm not even allowed to vote up the answers... Sorry about that guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Eclipse User Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm):

Open the Java Build Path dialog (Project > Properties > Java Build Path) and go to the **Projects** tab.

> In the **Required projects on the build
>   path list**, you can add project
>   dependencies by selecting other
>   workbench projects to add to the build
>   path for this new project.
>
> Adding a required project indirectly
>   adds all its classpath entries marked
>   as 'exported'. Setting a classpath
>   entry as exported is done in the Order
>   and Export tab

Comment: Thanks, I added foo to the build path under the "projects" tab. But then it fails when trying to resolve the imports in webapp. Is there anything else that needs to be done as well? (And if I do F3 on a foo method in foo-webapp it says "the resource is not on the build path").

Comment: @YMA: make sure the Foo project is open.  In the 'order and export' tab of Foo's build path, make sure your source folders are set to export, as are the libraries that you would also need in webapp.  It _should_ work.

Comment: Just found the issue - see my edit to the question. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Simple add the "Foo Engine" project as a dependency to the "Foo Webapp" project.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to work (see my reply to dogbane).